# How could I show only the validation error from all this response?

Tags: php, json, salesforce, response

I am passing values to salesforce api and want only to display validation error which is showing in last line of this response. I have already tried as following code but it showing blank.

```
echo $json_response->{'message'};
echo $json_response['message'];
```

I getting response like following. and i want to show only ""
ErrorCode 001,validation error : Invalid PAN

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 06:45:08 GMT Set-Cookie: BrowserId=2fIw353WRuq31pLHIKvYEA;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sun, 01-May-2016 06:45:08 GMT Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked " message - ErrorCode 001,validation error : Invalid PAN"
```

My code is as following

```
<?php session_start();
$json=$_SESSION['json'];
$details=json_decode($json);
//var_dump($details);
$name='LoanCreationService';
$instance_url='https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/';
$access_token = $details->{'access_token'};
create_account($name, $instance_url, $access_token);
//echo $message->{'message'};
function create_account($name, $instance_url, $access_token) {
    $url = $instance_url;
    //$content = json_encode(array("Name" => $name));
    $content=$_SESSION['content'];;
    //echo $content;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
                "Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    //echo $json_response;
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


    if ($output === false || $status != 200) {
      $output = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $status . "]";
      if (curl_error($curl))
        $output .= "\n". curl_error($curl);
      }

    //echo "HTTP status $status creating account<br/><br/>";
    echo $json_response;

    curl_close($curl);

   $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

    echo $id = $response["id"];

    return $id;
}
?>
```

Comment: The response body does not seem json ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str='Error: call to URL https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/ failed with status 200, response HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 12:29:37 GMT Set-Cookie: BrowserId=uWnPGUbLTo6CEe_X-k8ttA;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 30-Apr-2016 12:29:37 GMT Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked "success: Loan Application Number - 804326964", curl_error , curl_errno 0';
$del="Loan Application Number";
$pos=(string)strpos($str, $del);
if($pos==NULL){
    //echo $important=substr($str, $pos+strlen($del)+3, 9);
    echo "You have some error";
    }

else{
    echo $important=substr($str, $pos+strlen($del)+3, 9);
    }
?>
```